# Export csv via pscustomobject displaying incorrectly powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have the following code:

```
    function realtest
    {
         $files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\data\' -Filter *.csv
         $tester = [PSCustomObject]@{

         foreach ($file in $files)
         {
             $tempName = $file.BaseName
             $temp = Import-Csv $file
             $tester | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $tempName -Value $temp.$tempName
         }
         $tester
         $tester | Export-Csv "D:\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

I am trying to export a bunch of data to CSV however when it is display the data on csv it is shown as below

```
"E0798T102","E0798T103"
"System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
```

but when i do it as a print on console it displays as the below

```
E0798T102       E0798T103
---------       ---------
{0, 0, 0, 0...} {0, 0, 0, 0...}
```

Ultimately, I want E0798T102 and E0798T103 as seperate columns in the result.csv

just to note, I will have 50 csv to loop through and each should display as its own column

Comment: Based on your code, it appears each CSV file has the base name of each file as the first and only column header with only one row of data. Is this correct? Or does each CSV file contain only one column with the file base name as a header and many rows where you ultimately want one CSV file with 50 columns of varying row counts?

Comment: Yes that is correct but there is only one column in each csv file with 500 rows of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an incredibly inefficient answer to your question. If left as is, it assumes your CSV files already have a header with the CSV file basename:

```
$CSVs = Get-ChildItem -path 'D:\data\' -filter "*.csv" -file
$headers = $CSVs.basename
$table = [System.Data.DataTable]::new("Files")
foreach ($header in $headers) {
    $table.Columns.Add($header) | out-null
}
foreach ($CSV in $CSVs) {
    #$contents = Import-Csv $CSV -Header $CSV.basename # If CSV has no header
    $contents = Import-Csv $CSV # If CSV contains header
    $rowNumber = 0
    foreach ($line in $Contents) {
        $rowcount = $table.rows.count
        if ($rowNumber -ge $rowCount) {
            $row = $table.NewRow()
            $row[$CSV.basename] = $line.$($CSV.basename)
            $table.Rows.Add($row)

        }
        else {
            $row = $table.rows[$rowNumber]
            $row[$CSV.basename] = $line.$($CSV.basename)

        }

        $rowNumber++
    }
}
$table | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You can uncomment the commented `$contents` line if your CSV files do not have a header. You will just have to comment out the next `$contents` variable assignment if you uncomment the first.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippet, this can be significantly simplified:

```
function Get-Csv {
    $col = foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path D:\data -Filter *.csv) {
        $csv = Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName
        [pscustomobject]@{
            $csv.($file.BaseName) = $csv
        }
    }
    $col | Export-Csv D:\result.csv -NoTypeInformation

    return $col
}
```

*However*, a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file seems like the wrong approach because you're trying to embed *objects* under a header.  This doesn't really work in a tabular format as you only get one layer of depth.  You should either expand all the properties on your objects, or use a different format that can represent depth, like [json](/questions/tagged/json).

The reason for your formatting woes is due to how the serialization works.  You're getting a string representation of your objects.

Converting to [json](/questions/tagged/json) isn't difficult, you just trade your `Export-Csv` call:

```
$col | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File -FilePath D:\result.json
```

*Note: I specify `-Depth 100` because the cmdlet's default `Depth` is `2`.*

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.

I am trying to run your code but i get the following error 
`Import-Csv : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.
At line:181 char:24
+         $csv = $file | Import-Csv

A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At line:183 char:13
+             $csv.($file.BaseName) = $csv`

Comment: I re-ran it again using the updated script you have written and this is the result i get `System.Object[]
---------------
{@{E0798T102=0}, @{E0798T102=0}, @{E0798T102=0}, @{E0798T102=0}...}
{@{E0798T103=0}, @{E0798T103=0}, @{E0798T103=0}, @{E0798T103=0}...}
`

In the csv file i get the following
`System.Object[]
System.Object[]
System.Object[]
`

Comment: Thank you for your support but AdminOfThings just did a script which worked perfectly.